# Changing BLE MTU on a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm going to apologize if this has been answered anywhere else, but I was unable to find a solution listed anywhere online. (Or even know where to start)

I've managed to create a Windows Store App using Visual Studio, on a Windows 8.1 OS (Using C# as my programming language). As part of establishing a BLE connection with a device, I'm using the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile to perform the various steps in establishing and maintaining a BLE connection.

Now, there are a few moments in which I need to send more than 20 bytes of data to a connected device. I've looked into changing the MTU, but I was unable to find any good sources on **how** to change the MTU on a Windows Store App. Any helpful documents or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum Link Layer Data Field packet Length minus 4 byte header for BLE4.0/4.1 is 23 bytes and for BLE4.2 251 bytes. There is now way you can change that in your App.
Another thing to consider is that most simple BLE-devices you can connect to only accept packets of 20 bytes.
So if you want to send more data than 20 bytes just send multiple packets and don't forget to wait for **GattCommunicationStatus.Success** before sending the next packet.

Comment: The device is already using BLE4.2, but it seems to have a default size of 23. Is there any method where I can have the app and the device compromise on the size of the messages being sent? If possible, I'd prefer to not send data over in multiple packets as that would interfere with the device's current functionality.

Comment: Just a minor correction to GrooverFromHolland's comment, the minimum ATT_MTU for BLE is 23 bytes but there isn't a theoretical maximum. As for raw BLE packet, the minimum is 27 bytes and the maximum is 251.

Comment: @yousif saeed You are right,.
Here is a important note from T.I. on this:
Due to memory and processing limitations, not all Bluetooth low energy systems support larger MTU sizes. Know the capabilities of expected peer devices when defining the behavior of the system. If the capability of peer devices is unknown, design the system to work with the default 27-byte L2CAP PDU/23-byte ATT_MTU size. For example, sending notifications with a length greater than 20 bytes (ATT_MTU-3) bytes results in truncation of data on devices that do not support larger MTU sizes.

Comment: That is sound advice and I have personally come across scenarios where two devices do not know each other's ATT_MTU and end up having issues such as data loss. Thank you for the info.

Comment: This statement is wrong. There is no limitation of ATT MTU in any Bluetooth version. For Version 4.0 and newer, ATT MTU can be up to 65535, as long as it's supported by both devices. I think you might mix it up with the LE Data Length extension, which is a link layer optimization and does not affect the host layers.

Comment: You are absolutely right Emil. I meant the Link Layer Data Field  packet Length minus 4 byte header, not ATT_MTU.